# Displaying the IssueTypes and Issues of a Component in a JIRA template

Tags: jira, velocity

In the Release Notes velocity template ( [jira-install-dir]\atlassian-jira\WEB-INF\classes\templates\jira\project\releasenotes\releasenotes-html.vm ), the issues shown are organized under IssueTypes:

**Bug**

- Issue 1
- Issue 2...

**Improvement**

- Issue 1
- Issue 2...

I am trying to find a way to organize IssueTypes and Issues under Components, OR Components and Issues under IssueTypes:

**Component**

- Bug

  - Issue 1
  - Issue 2...
- Improvement

  - Issue 1
  - Issue 2...

OR

**Bug**

- Component A

  - Issue 1
  - Issue 2...
- Component B

  - Issue 1
  - Issue 2...

**Improvement**

- Component A

  - Issue 1
  - Issue 2...

Currently it grabs the issues from each issueType:

```
#foreach ($issueType in $issueTypes)
  #if($issueType.issues.size() > 0)
    <h2>$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name)</h2>
    <ul>
    #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
      <li>[<a href='$!appProps.getString("jira.baseurl")/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>]
      $textUtils.htmlEncode($issue.summary)#getReleaseNoteLoggedonBehalfof($issue
      $customFieldManager)</li>
    #end
    </ul>
  #end
#end
```

I'd like to accomplish something like this (pseudo code... excuse the nested loops it's just how my brain is working right now, I'll write less code when I have more time! :P)

```
#foreach ($component in $components)
  #foreach ($issueType in $component.issueTypes)
    #if($issueType.issues.size() > 0)
      <h2>$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name)</h2>
      <ul>
      #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
        <li>[<a href='$!appProps.getString("jira.baseurl")/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>]
        $textUtils.htmlEncode($issue.summary)#getReleaseNoteLoggedonBehalfof($issue
        $customFieldManager)</li>
      #end
      </ul>
    #end
  #end
#end
```

Can I access the Issues/IssueTypes of a Component through a Velocity template? Alternatively, if there is a better way to accomplish this I'm all ears!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because Jira uses the MVC pattern in velocity you have only access to data provided by controller. It seems that only $issueTypes are relevant data for you and so in general there is no way to get unique list of components which are required to render such a structure.

I therefore suggest to write an own plugin module (for example report).
Fetch and organize your issues in java to have a structure List> components and then should be easy for you to render it.